# Rate of approximation by polynomials to a C1 function(Weierstras Approximation thm)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence, weierstrass-approximation

By Weierstrass Approximation theorem, a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$ can be uniformly approximated by polynomials. But if the function $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$, then we can actually say something about the *rate* of approximation. That is, if $\epsilon > 0$, then $f$ can be approximated uniformly within $\epsilon$ by a polynomial of degree not greater than $N = N(\epsilon)$. How can I find $N(\epsilon)$?

It is trivial that $f'$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials since it is continuous in $[0,1]$ too, but I don't know whether this has something to do with solving the problem.

Comment: Would you be interested in that kind of result for trigonometric polynomials? Jackson's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson%27s_inequality) and Berstein's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(approximation_theory)) relate very closely the regularity and the rate of convergence of the best approximations

Comment: Is this saying $N$ doesn't depend on $f$?

Comment: I'm looking for ordinary polynomials, as the original theorem says about. I'm not sure about the textbook's meaning(about whether $N$ depends on $f$), but I will appreciate both types of solutions.

Comment: There is also a form of Jackson's inequality for "normal" polynomials. See here https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Jackson_inequality

Comment: I read it, and it is much more difficult than I expected.